# mysqldump without "SET GLOBAL ..." in the dumped file

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to restore a mysql dumpped file to an AWS RDS MySQL instance.

The command I used to restore the dumpped file is

```
mysql --user=${DB_USER} --password=${DB_PASSWORD} --default-character-set=utf8 --host=${target_rds_endpiont} < dumppped_file.sql
```

This command generates the following error:

```
ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 14: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

Line 14 of the dumpped file is `/*!50606 SET GLOBAL INNODB_STATS_AUTO_RECALC=OFF */;`.

Is there any way to use mysqldump to create a dumpped file that doesn't contain `SET GLOBAL ....`?

Because `INNODB_STATS_AUTO_RECALC` is stored in the parameter group of an RDS instance. I don't need this when restoring from a dumpped file.

[This docuemnt](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/mysqldump-error-rds-mysql-mariadb/) doesn't have a solution for my error.

I can't find any solution in the document of `man mysqldump`, either.

Comment: You may remove such instructions from the dump - but this may result in another errors and incorrect restoring result. Ask the hoster either to provide needed permission to you or to restore your dump using the account with needed privileges.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to remove line 14 from the dump file, allowing it to continue. Make sure to temporarily set INNODB_STATS_AUTO_RECALC to 0 on the database parameter group settings

```
awk 'NR==14 { print "" ; next } 1' backup-file.sql > new-backup-file.sql
```

It will take a long time if the file is huge

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).